# Storing data but being able to search it (database encryption)

Tags: mongodb, encryption, aes, database

Im trying to work through the architecture for a database that I need to protect the email addresses stored in it. Its a Mongo database and each document stores two email addresses and a load of other content. I want to make sure that the document is not attributable to the email addresses, however when my program needs to access the document it can access the email addresses too. It also may need searching by email address.

My understanding. Hash the email addresses before storing using AES256 (or similar symmetric encryption standard). 
Store the database somewhere other than the program (and the key).
When you need to be able to search for the email address, encrypt the email query with the key and search for this in the DB. When you find it, pull all the documents.
You can then decrypt the other email address that wasn't used for search.

Seems fine, but where do you store the key? In an enviroment variable? But if the server has been hacked, then whats the point in the encryption?
On a seperate server?

What is database encryption protecting against? Just the database dump being stolen or the server getting accessed?

Please could someone walk me through how this is done as industry standard?

Thanks

Comment: don't use encryption, use a one-way hash and salt. i like sha3. you should not be able to recover the address from the DB, without brute-forcing. this means, obviously, that you cannot search for a partial email match, but only for the whole correct email address.

Comment: but what about a situation where I search for one email address and want to understand the other email address? This cant be done with hashing, so I feel it must be encrypted. Its a really annoying scenario otherwise I could have gone with hashing. I'm wondering whether I store a username against each email, then get the other email address, search for it in the user DB and grab the username. That way I don't need to decrypt, but does mean a different architecture (and a username may be associatable with a user

Comment: i don't see why you can't use a has every place that would use an email. you can have a separate db to convert hashes to clear emails if needed for reporting, but hashes and emails should be interchangeable in terms of database storage and access: they are both short amounts of text.